# Calculate BBOX by latitude and longitude

Tags: openlayers, c#, bbox

How openlayers3 generate BBOX by latitude and longitude.

I want to generate BBOX for GetFeatureInfo request by latitude and longitude in C#.

Comment: GetFeatureInfo is only valid for a point

Comment: GetFeatureInfo is a WMS thing. OpenLayers3 is a javascript front-end framework. Where does C# come in?

Comment: seems quite on-topic to me